# Is it possible to inject pure Java code into Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Actually I don't need this feature and asking just out of interest.

With `C` language it's possible to use assembler code within source code.

Is it possible with Kotlin?

For instance, define `inline fun` with `@Java` annotation. As the result all invocations of this function will be replaced with bytecode as it was compiled by `javac`.

Comment: `kotlinc` already does compile to bytecode, just like `javac`

Comment: I'm aware of that

Comment: do you mean mixing Java and Kotlin code in the same file? Unfortunately that's not possible

Comment: then I don't understand what you mean by " replaced with bytecode as it was compiled by javac" - since both bytecodes are basically identical

Comment: ah, do you mean ignoring all kotlin custom things, like `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull`?

Comment: for instance use Java's `assert` statement. but as @user2340612 mentioned, seems it's impossible

Comment: @Lovis or just use plain old `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you could write a method which takes Java code as a string, wraps it into a class and uses [`javax.tools.JavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to compile it and use it as e.g.

```
val x = inlineJava[Int]("""
int sum = 0;
int size = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { sum++; }
return sum;
""")
```

(actually implementing `inlineJava` left as an exercise). Though I must admit I can't think of a good reason to.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A Kotlin file (.kt) can only contain Kotlin code. You can create a Java file (.java) and use it interchangeably with your Kotlin code, though.